# How to run the Google app engine server using Dockerfile

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, web2py

I'm new to docker, i need to run the web2py application in google app engine server using Dockerfile for this i created the dockerfile to install the python, gae server and my web2py source folder.

my issues are one how to start the gae server using Dockerfile and how to configure the existing source code into gae and how to run the gae server to view the my application landing page on browser based on the docker running container IP

here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER John
#install python
RUN sudo apt-get install python --assume-yes
RUN apt-get install -y wget unzip
#install GAE
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-    sdk.zip && unzip google-cloud-sdk.zip && rm google-cloud-sdk.zip
RUN google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=true --path-update=true --  bash-completion=true --rc-path=/.bashrc --additional-components app-engine-python 
ENV PATH /google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH

COPY Testapp/ . 
RUN pwd 
WORKDIR Testapp
CMD python web2py.py  
#Expose the ports
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["/Testapp/web2py"]
#CMD ["python", "/Testapp/web2py.py"]
CMD ["/bash/"]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are doing? I'm not even sure where you are using Google App Engine. You are installing the sdk in the docker image, but you never use it... Are you trying to develop an app that will run on Google App Engine servers?

Comment: I have already developed web2py app, that one i need to run in google app engine using docker image for that i created above Dockerfile. by using the below Dockerfile i'm able to start the google app engine but getting the below error

Comment: INFO     2015-12-15 04:49:52,991 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2015-12-15 04:49:53,997 simple_search_stub.py:1126] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.cfsatestapp.root/search_indexes
INFO     2015-12-15 04:49:54,022 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:56568
INFO     2015-12-15 04:49:54,537 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2015-12-15 04:49:54,543 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Chandra
#install python
RUN apt-get install -y -qq wget python unzip
#install GAE
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-sdk.zip && unzip google-cloud-sdk.zip && rm google-cloud-sdk.zip
RUN google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=true --path-update=true --bash-completion=true --rc-path=/.bashrc --additional-components app-engine-python
ENV PATH /google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR CFSA_Testapp
COPY CFSA_Testapp/ .
RUN pwd
CMD python guestbook.py
#Expose the ports
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["dev_appserver.py", "--host=0.0.0.0", "."]
```

I tested it using [Google's example app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python) simply by putting it in `CFSA_Testapp` folder.

You can run it with `docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 image_name`.

Then you just open your browser on `localhost:8080` and you are done.

Comment: INFO     2015-12-15 04:49:52,991 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2015-12-15 04:49:53,997 simple_search_stub.py:1126] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.cfsatestapp.root/search_indexes
INFO     2015-12-15 04:49:54,022 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:56568
INFO     2015-12-15 04:49:54,537 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2015-12-15 04:49:54,543 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000

Comment: getting the " WARNING 2015-12-15 04:49:53,997 simple_search_stub.py:1126] Could not read search indexes from " and unable to get the landing page of the application on browser using localhost:8080

Comment: "Could not read search indexes from" shows up, because there is no index yet. It will be created at that very point. You can tweak storage location with options of `dev_appserver.py`

Comment: i tried with storage location options of dev_appserver.py but no luck. so i tried with my ip r port i.e 10.10.10.60:8080

Comment: EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["dev_appserver.py", "--host=10.10.10.60", "."] , getting below error and i tried with different ports i.e 9090, 9000 ... etc but no luck

Comment: File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 352, in _start_all_fixed_port
    raise BindError('Unable to bind %s:%s' % self.bind_addr)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind 10.10.10.60:8080

Comment: Binding to 0.0.0.0 is really needed here. It's not IP of your docker host but one within this particular docker container. So 0.0.0.0 guarantee your app will be visible from outside container. Is it possible to point me to the git repo with the app?

Comment: vagrant@node6:~/dockerfiles/dfs/python$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
88bd79a48ba2        registry.local/python   "dev_appserver.py /D   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   focused_pasteur
vagrant@node6:~/dockerfiles/dfs/python$ curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
vagrant@node6:~/dockerfiles/dfs/python$ curl http://0.0.0.0:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: while running using curl also its not hit the server

Comment: That mean you are close :) I just tried using your repo and I was greeted with login to "Online Booking System". `0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp` means that container binded to 8080 on your host/vagrant machine so you should use localhost:8080 or IP of vagrant (when accessing from outside vagrant but that might involve extra work)

Comment: yeah,I tried using http://localhost:8080 and 10.10.10.60:8080 IP of vagrant  but no luck, need any extra settings or am i miss any thing in any where

Comment: vagrant@node6:~/dockerfiles/dfs/python$ docker logs f3e
INFO     2015-12-23 12:58:46,169 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2015-12-23 12:58:46,539 simple_search_stub.py:1126] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.auktestapp.root/search_indexes
INFO     2015-12-23 12:58:46,545 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:56683
INFO     2015-12-23 12:58:46,636 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-12-23 12:58:46,639 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000

Comment: vagrant@node6:~/dockerfiles/dfs/python$ ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.10.60
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1
vagrant@node6:~/dockerfiles/dfs/python$ curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: vagrant@node6:~/dockerfiles/dfs/python$ curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server